# Wordpress - Form options.php - How to not overwrite a setting if it didn't found the name attribute for this setting

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a plugin wordpress.

I have a form with inside some inputs tags except one (for this one, I use ajax and update_option, so we don't need to submit this form to update this setting). 
When I submit this form, options.php didn't found a name for a setting, so it overwrites this setting with an empty value.

I would like to know how I can avoid this ? I would like to avoid to do a hidden input, because this plugin is not finish at all, I don't want to have 50 hidden inputs at the end... I want it to keep the values if it doesn't found a name for the setting.

**EDIT :** One of the solution I found is to have differents forms and differents option group for the register_setting. I have 4 forms, so I have 4 options groups, that works, I wanted something better, but it's ok !

Answer (score 0):

For the update value you need to use:

```
<?php update_option( 'my_custom_option', get_the_ID() ); ?>
```

NOTE: Please add the ID for the update.

You need to check this option values into wordpress wp_options table.
All the option data will be save into `wp_options`.

Get the option value by this function:

```
$my_custom_option = get_option( 'my_custom_option' );
var_dump( $my_custom_option );
```

OR

```
$my_custom_option = get_option( 'my_custom_option', get_the_ID() );
    var_dump( $my_custom_option );
```

Comment: I already use update_option and get_option, it works fine ! But it didn't answer my question .. ^^